# How do use 'input type="Submit" OnServerClick=' from codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net

Troubleshooting an IIS Session State problem I found a simple page to use as a test. This page works.

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input type="text"
        id="text1"  
        runat="server"
        />
        <input type="Submit"
        id="Submit1" 
        OnServerClick="Session_Add" 
        value="Add to Session State" 
        runat="server"
            />
        <input type="Submit"
        id="Submit2"  
        OnServerClick="CheckSession" 
        value="View Session State" 
        runat="server" 
        />
        <hr size="1"/>
        <font size="6"/><span id="span1" runat="server"/>
    </div>
</form>
<script language="C#" runat="server">
    void Session_Add(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["MySession"] = text1.Value;
        span1.InnerHtml = "Session data updated! <P> Your session contains: <font color=red>" +
                    Session["MySession"].ToString() + "</font>";
    }

    void CheckSession(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["MySession"].ToString()))
        {
            span1.InnerHtml = "NOTHING, SESSION DATA LOST!";
        }
        else
            span1.InnerHtml = "Your session contains: <font color=red>" +
                     Session["MySession"].ToString() + "</font>";
    }
</script>
```

For no particular reason other than I wanted to do it that way, I tried moving the part in the script block to a codebehind file. That code follows:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Submit1.ServerClick += new System.EventHandler(this.Session_Add);
        Submit2.ServerClick += new System.EventHandler(this.CheckSession);


    }

    void Session_Add(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["MySession"] = text1.Value;
        span1.InnerHtml = "Session data updated! <P> Your session contains: <font color=red>" +
                    Session["MySession"].ToString() + "</font>";
    }

    void CheckSession(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ( String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["MySession"].ToString())) 
        {
            span1.InnerHtml = "NOTHING, SESSION DATA LOST!";
        }
        else
            span1.InnerHtml = "Your session contains: <font color=red>" +             
                     Session["MySession"].ToString() + "</font>";
    }

}
```

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.webform1_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Session_Add' and no extension method 'Session_Add' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.webform1_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What would I have to do to make this work?

Comment: Dont think you can do that.

Try changing it to an asp:button server control (so it wires up the event handlers properly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="YourPageName.aspx.cs" Inherits="ClassNameOfCodeBehindeWithFullNamespace" %>`

above needs to be there on top of your your aspx page

**UPDATE**
You need to add `protected` modifier for your methods.

Comment: <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SessionStateTester.aspx.cs" Inherits="SessionStateStuff.WebForm1" %>

Is what was there. The codebehind was created at the same time as the aspx using VS 2010. And it compiles OK, it is a runtime error.