# HTML Button with an OnServerClick not finding method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm getting the following error when attempting to build my application:

> CS1061: 'ASP.mailbox_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'MarkAsRead' and no extension method 'MarkAsRead' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.mailbox_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

But everything seems to be in place as it should be - unless there's something I'm missing?

HTML:

```
<button id="markasread" runat="server" class="btn btn-white btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Mark as read" onserverclick="MarkAsRead"><i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i> </button>
```

C#:

```
private void MarkAsRead(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (RepeaterItem aItem in rptInbox.Items)
            {
                HtmlInputCheckBox chkDisplayTitle = (HtmlInputCheckBox)aItem.FindControl("chkDisplayTitle");
                if (chkDisplayTitle.Checked)
                {
                    var messageid = chkDisplayTitle.Value;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you post more of your code (both the code behind as well as the markup)?

Comment: chage private to protected. possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159349/how-do-use-input-type-submit-onserverclick-from-codebehind .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your method is `private`:-

```
protected void MarkAsRead(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

When you define the control in aspx page, it is compiled into a class which is inherited by code behind class. So in your case it is not able to find the method you have defined in code behind class.